# What is com.android.vending.splits?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-manifest

What is this code in android-manifest used for?

What is the explanation?

```
<meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.splits" android:resource="@xml/splits0" />
<meta-data android:name="com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" android:value="3" />
```

Comment: AFAIK it is an internal XMl configuration file about split APK files (app bundle).

Answer (score -2):

The package name "com.android.vending.splits" refers to a component of the Android operating system related to the Google Play Store app. This specific component is responsible for managing split APKs.

Split APKs are a feature introduced in Android to overcome the limitations of the 100MB size restriction for APK files. When an app exceeds this limit, developers can split the APK into multiple smaller files called split APKs. Each split APK contains a specific part of the app's resources or code, such as language resources or device architecture-specific code.

In your provided code snippet, the  elements within the  or  section are used to define metadata information about the app's APK splits.

The first  element specifies the resource file for the splits configuration. It points to an XML file named "splits0". This file likely contains information about how the app's APK is divided into split APKs.

The second  element with the name "com.android.vending.derived.apk.id" and value "3" is related to the Play Store app's internal tracking of APKs. This metadata is used by the Play Store to keep track of different versions of the app and ensure proper updates and compatibility.

Comment: "Split APKs are a feature introduced in Android to overcome the limitations of the 100MB size restriction for APK files. " This is totally wrong. Split APKs allow to minimize the APK size for each device as you only send those splits that are really necessary for the device (e.g. one split APK for arm64, one for the language and another for high-dpi). Small APKs save flash memory when installed and Google also saves network capacity as they don't have to transmit unnecessary APK parts.